# Use unique line from text file per device

Tags: python

This is something that is bothering me and since I am new to python and programming I don't have idea what I am doing wrong.
So what I am trying to achieve is I've a text file with 2 lines of proxy and I've a function that returns 2 device in form of list and I want to use 1 proxy per 1 device however with my below code I am being ended up with same proxy on both the devices and that too last line of proxy file.

my sample text file contains following values

```
111.111.111.111:200211
111.121.121.121:200212
```

below is my code. Hope someone can help me with this.

```
from ppadb.client import Client as AdbClient

client = AdbClient(host="127.0.0.1", port=5037)
devices = client.devices()
with open('F:/Appium/venv/proxy.txt') as file:
    proxy_file = file.readline()
    for device in devices:
        device.shell("settings put global http_proxy "+ str(proxy_file) +"")
        print(device)
        print(proxy_file)
```

Below is the output

```
<ppadb.device.Device object at 0x0000027AE38AD100>
123.133.232.44:2502

<ppadb.device.Device object at 0x0000027AE38ADB80>
123.133.232.44:2502


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would help if you show a sample of the two files, and one of your intended output.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what's your end goal. Do you want to use for each `device` a unique `proxy_file`?

Comment: I've added my sample file that I am using and yes I want to use a unique proxy file for unique device
With the present state of code it uses only last line of the sample text in both the devices.
I hope I explained it more clearly

Comment: I can see issues with your code (and I would instead approach it like [Hai Vu's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69318620/12975140)), but at the same time I can't understand why it would give output quite like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plan is to get a list of devices and a list of proxies. Then you can use the `zip` function to "zip" (combine) them together.

```py
from ppadb.client import Client as AdbClient

client = AdbClient(host="127.0.0.1", port=5037)
devices = client.devices()
with open('F:/Appium/venv/proxy.txt') as stream:
    proxies = [line.strip() for line in stream]

for device, proxy in zip(devices, proxies):
    device.shell("settings put global http_proxy "+ str(proxy) +"")
    print(device)
    print(proxy_file)
```

Comment: The only potential issue with this is if there are more devices than listed proxies. In that case some devices won't get set. If that's not likely to occur, then no worries. If it is, you could use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) instead, `break` if `device is None`, and raise an error or print a message of some sort if `proxy is None`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that your `device` is using a given `proxy`, so that they form a pair, one way to do it is to map those value together in a dictionary, to obtain a "pair" `device`:`proxy` in something that looks like

```py
devices_to_proxies = {}

with open('F:/Appium/venv/proxy.txt') as file:
    for device in devices:
        devices_to_proxies[device] = file.readline()
for device, proxy in devices_to_proxies.items():
    device.shell(f"settings put global http_proxy {proxy}")
```

Comment: Unless the dictionary is needed later for other purposes, you could also skip that step and simply set each proxy in the first `for` loop.

Comment: Yeah, it's simply one way to do it. Since no other clarification are given, I assumed that he'll need that information stored. Also, I assume that the proxies' file is well formatted. Thanks for the clarifications, by the way